# Почему появилась ошибка сегментирования NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, elf

Не могу понять, что не так с кодом
Ошибка на строке "cmp [rax+rbx],byte 0" (проверял в gdb), но ведь для 64 архитектуры такая команда дозволена(?)
Заранее спасибо

```
segment .text
global _start

_start:
mov rax,'571'
call _string_to_num
call _print_line

call exit



_string_to_num:
push rdx
push rcx
push rbx
xor rbx,rbx
xor rcx,rcx

_iter:

cmp [rax+rbx], byte 0
je _prepare_to_convert
mov cl,[rax+rbx]
sub cl,'0'
inc rbx
push rcx                ; steck 5 7 1
jmp _iter

_prepare_to_convert:
    mov rcx,1
    mov rax,0
    _convert_to_num:
        cmp rbx,0
        je close
        pop rdx
        imul rdx,rcx          ; 1*1 7*10 5*100
        imul rcx,10
        add rax,rdx
        dec rbx
        jmp _convert_to_num
 close:
 pop rbx
 pop rcx
 pop rdx
 ret 


_strlen:
push rdx
xor rdx,rdx
_strlen_loop_start:
    je _strlen_loop_end
    inc rdx
    jmp _strlen_loop_start

_strlen_loop_end:
    mov rax,rdx
    pop rdx
    ret

_print_line:

push rax
push rbx
push rcx
push rdx
mov rcx, rax

call _strlen

mov rdx,rax
mov rax,4
mov rbx,1
syscall

pop rdx
pop rcx
pop rbx
pop rax
ret



exit:
mov rax,1
mov rbx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: как ты думаешь, что делает эта `mov rax,'571'` команда?

Comment: Ошибку понял. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В rax нужно загрузить строку с переменной, а не напрямую. К тому же используется подпрограмма вывода строки, а не числа, которое возвращается в rax